# Which data structure i should use to define and store users actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, data-structures, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension uses the drag and drop feature, it works in this way:

You grab an object from a source page and drop it to a target page, this event corresponded to a set of predefined instructions (let's say 3 async functions). After a while you drag again another object and drop it to the same area, a popup message asks whether to substitute or merge the two objects (to commit this operation you need to read what is done in the past).

I wonder, which data structure(perhaps stack), approach to use in order to set logical interpretation of the instructions.

Comment: A stack is LIFO, while your description sounds like FIFO. A queue would be an obvious choice (one queue for every region on the page).

Comment: @RobW indeed, I thought so .. Yet I can't figure out how to map every event with an appropriate set of instruction!

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?